# How to do an infinite loop from k to a given number and back to zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want something like (if starting from `2`):

`2, 3, ..., n-1, n, n-1, ..., 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (forever)`

Is there something simpler than this?:

```
def print_numbers_forth_and_back_forever(first_number, upper_limit):
    for i in range(first_number, upper_limit):
        print(i)
    while True:
        # back from n to 0
        for i in reversed(range(0, upper_limit+1)):
            print(i)
        # 1 to n-1
        for i in range(1, upper_limit):
            print(i)


print_numbers_forth_and_back_forever(4, 10)
```

Comment: Take a look at [itertoools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html); this seems like a combination of `chain()`and `cycle()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following using `itertools` will provide a generator that should fulfil the requirements - simply alter the arguments of `range(a, b)` to alter the output:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

r = range(10)
r_reversed = reversed(r[1:-1])
gen = cycle(chain(r, r_reversed))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(gen, 20))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

To start at an arbitrary integer, use the `start` argument for `islice` as follows:

```
>>> list(islice(gen, 4, 20))
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ah, I'd interpreted that as wanting to loop between, say, `4` and `10 `indefinitely. I'll update with the relevant arguments for `islice`.

Answer (score 2):

The same as you did with a generator :

```
# you can add start argument to replace 0
def gen_infinite_bounce(first, end) :
  yield from range(first,end)
  while True:
    yield from range(end, 0, -1)
    yield from range(0, end)

first = 2 # first Value
end = 5 # end bounce
# you can create a variable start to replace 0
for i in gen_infinite_bounce(first, end):
  print(i)
```

You can also do it with itertools :

```
first = 2 # first Value
end = 5 # end bounce
# you can create a variable start to replace 0
from itertools, import chain, cycle
for i in chain(
  range(first, end), cycle(
    chain(
      range(end, 0, -1),
      range(0, end)
    )
  )
):
  print(i)
```

Comment: What's `upper_limit` here is it `start`?

Comment: Oops copy paste fail :D it's end

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` with `range()` objects to efficiently create the output you want:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain, islice

def cycle_fwd_back(first, last):
    yield from range(first, last)
    yield from cycle(chain(reversed(range(last + 1)), range(1, last)))


# First 30
print(list(islice(cycle_fwd_back(4, 10), 30)))
```

Outputs:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7]
```

Comment: Uhm... why calling range three times and yielding separately the first time round?

Comment: for handling the first value to end, because after it bounces to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
def print_numbers_forth_and_back_forever(first_number, upper_limit):
inc = 
i = first_number
while True:
    if i == upper_limit:
        inc = -1
    elif i == 0:
        inc = 1
    print(i,end = ' ')
    i += inc
```